# jQuery Ajax issue loading XML locally - Safari Version 11.0 - Error: XMLHttpRequest cannot load .xml. Preflight response is not successful

Tags: javascript, ajax, safari, preflight

Today I installed 'Safari Version 11.0' - soon as I installed it i was having issues loading in local XML files over jQuery Ajax.

```
"XMLHttpRequest cannot load .xml. Preflight response is not successful"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easiest way to get around this is to enable the developer menu, and select "Disable local file restrictions" from the develop menu.

Hope this helps someone else..